# Separar header, content y footer en PDF con DomPDF

Tags: html, css, laravel-8, dompdf

Estoy usando el paquete *barryvdh/laravel-dompdf* para generar mi PDF, hasta aqui no he tenido mayor problema para ingresar los datos del formulario o agregar los estilos.
Mi problema principal es que no se como hacer para que en caso de pasarme los limites del pdf haga el salto de pagina en automatico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Coloco la imagen y el codigo css como referencia porque asi es como me genera el pdf y por más que intento no logro separar los 3 elementos.

```
@page {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 60px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        height: 50px;
    }
   
    header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0cm;
        left: 0cm;
        right: 0cm;
        height: 3cm;
    }
```

Agradeceria su ayuda muchas gracias.